# Node.js returning an error on a colon in JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I am trying to use node.js to read a JSON file server-side and reading it using fs. When I try to parse a JSON file, it works with a single object, but when reading an array, it gives an error on a colon. The server script is in the same directory as the JSON file, and I wrote my JSON file to comply with the directions shown at https://www.json.org/json-en.html.

Javascript code I am trying to run:

```
console.log('recived login request');
var obj = fs.readFileSync('userInfo.json');
console.log(JSON.parse(obj));
```

Json file code:

```
{ "test": [ "testUno" :"yes" ] }
```

(Note: the json file code shown is just a test)

Comment: well that is not valid JSON. Did you mean to use `{ "testUno" :"yes" }` or `["testUno", "yes"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it turns out I dont know how to write json but now I do. oops

Answer (score 0):

Also suggest considering code compatibility, please always use dictionary { } as root of json object.